# Knockout Validation, Mapping, and Dynamic Forms

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I've spent two days looking through possible answers and trying just about everything to see what might work. So forgive me if I've overlooked something. Here's the scenario.

Let's say I navigate to some url like `/#/register/:session` and this route fires of a JSON request for the the fields I want the user to fill out in order to register for this session. Something like this:

```
fieldsMapping = { "include": ["fields"] }

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, fieldsMapping, self.attendee.registration.registrationFields);
```

The response is just a JSON object that I map to a view model called registrationFields(). The JSON looks like this:

```
"fields": [
    { "field": "firstName", "required": true, "maxSize": 128 },
    { "field": "lastName", "required": true, "maxSize": 128 },
    { "field": "email", "required": true, "maxSize": 128 }
]
```

The next step would be to generate the HTML for whatever fields are in the response.

```
<div class="registration-fields" data-bind="foreach: webapp.attendee.registration.registrationFields.fields(), registrationFieldsLayout: true">
    <label data-bind="text: message('registration.registrant.field.' + field()), attr: { for: '#' + field() }"></label>
    <!-- ko if: field() === "firstName" || field() === "lastName" -->
     <input type="text" data-bind="attr: { id: '#' + field(), value: $parent.firstName, 'data-validate': (required()) ? true : false }">
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: field() === "email" -->
    <input type="email" data-bind="attr: { id: '#' + field(), value: $parent.email, 'data-validate': (required()) ? true : false }">
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

For the `$parent` variable, I'm attaching another view model for saving form data called RegistrationForm(). I do this in the form tag:

```
<form method="post" data-bind="with: webapp.attendee.registration.registrationForm">
```

The registrationForm() view model looks like this:

```
function (ko, validationRules) {

    return function RegistrationForm () {

        var self = this;

        validationRules();

        self.firstName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
        self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
        self.email = ko.observable().extend({ required: true, email: true });

        self.submit = function () {
            if (self.errors().length === 0) {
                console.log("hurrah");
            } else {
                console.log("errors should be shown");
                self.errors.showAllMessages();
            }
        }

        self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    }

}
```

Now, all of my view models are loaded with requirejs, which is great. But what happens is that my fields are not being attached to the RegistrationForm() view model after they're rendered, so the validation doesn't work.

If I put in a static field, the validation works just fine.

I've tried a lot of different things, but nothing seems to work. Hoping someone can help shed some light.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Nevermind. The problem was here:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr: { id: '#' + field(), value: $parent.firstName, 'data-validate': (required()) ? true : false }">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr: { id: '#' + field(), 'data-validate': (required()) ? true : false }, value: $parent.firstName">
```

Can't believe I missed that.